# {XOR} Constraint on two optional principals

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The following is my metamodel.

[image: metamodel]

By the above figure, instances of C must either belong to principal A or B -- not both.

How do I *properly* enforce that?
Currently I have the following property on C:

```
    [Required]
    [NotMapped]
    [Obsolete(message:"Internal. Only for validation!")]
    public string Constraint_A_Xor_B
    {
        get => A != null ^ B != null ? "Valid" : null;
        set { }
    }
```

It gets the job done by invalidating the [Required] constraints by returning null when the XOR constraint fails. I don't think it's proper to add a property to the class for this purpose.

**Can the constraint be enforced by other means?**

For completeness, what follows is the entire code.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace EF_CodeFirst_XOR
{
    using System.Data.Entity;

    public class XorDemo : DbContext
    {
        public XorDemo()
            : base("name=XorDemo")
        {
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Root> Roots { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<C> Cs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<C>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.A)
                .WithOptionalPrincipal(e => e.C);

            modelBuilder.Entity<C>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.B)
                .WithOptionalPrincipal(e => e.C);
        }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public int Id { get; set;}

        [Required]
        public A A { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public B B { get; set; }
    }

    public class A
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey(nameof(Root))]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual C C { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual Root Root { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey(nameof(Root))]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual C C { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual Root Root { get; set; }
    }

    public class C
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }


        public virtual A A { get; set; }
        public virtual B B { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [NotMapped]
        [Obsolete(message:"Internal. Only for validation!")]
        public string Constraint_A_Xor_B
        {
            get => A != null ^ B != null ? "Valid" : null;
            set { }
        }

    }
}
```

*Edit: The driver.*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ctx = new XorDemo();

        Root r = new Root();

        r.A = new A {Root = r};

        C Ca = new C();
        r.A.C = Ca;
        Ca.A = r.A;


        r.B = new B {Root = r};
        C Cb = new C {B = r.B};

        ctx.Roots.Add(r);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's Entity Framework that's validating the values there? It matters because most alternatives are more framework-specific, either working only on the EF side, or not working with EF.

Comment: I'm positive.
EF Version 6.
I've added the driver to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually not implement that in the mapping, but I'd do it in the data entity itself, with something along the lines of :

```
public class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private virtual A _a;
    public virtual A A
    {
        get
        {
            return _a;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("A", "You must have A or B.");

            if (_b != null)
                throw new ConstraintException("You can either have A or B; make up your mind!");

            if (value != _a)
                _a = value;
        }
    }

    private virtual B _b;
    public virtual B B
    {
        get
        {
            return _b;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("B", "You must have A or B.");

            if (_a != null)
                throw new ConstraintException("You can either have A or B; make up your mind!");

            if (value != _b)
                _b = value;
        }
    }

    public class C(A a)
    {
        if (a == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("a");

        this._a = a;
    }

    public class C(B b)
    {
        if (b == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("b");

        this._b = b;
    }

    public SwitchBforA(A a)
    {
        if (a == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("a", "You'd end up with both A and B null.");

        _a = a;
        _b = null;
    }

    public SwitchAforB(B b)
    {
        if (b == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("b", "You'd end up with both A and B null.");

        _a = null;
        _b = b;
    }
}
```

You should probably also add the constraint the usual way in the database.

Comment: This is a good solution, one which I did not think of. It works in my case!
A note to others: this solution provides on-line validation semantics, as opposite to validating after a call to ctx.save().

Comment: The reason why I'd do that in the data class is also that you'd see the problem when it happens, and not when you're trying to save further down the line,  most likely in another assembly and class!

Comment: On a second thought, the semantics of your solution are OR instead of XOR. I need to force XOR.

Comment: Sorry, that was a big oversight. I just edited my answer. By forcing to use either constructor, it should do it. The "Switch" methods are optional; there there to allow an object that was meant to have an A to have a B, and vice-versa.